# FFMPEG hangs when trying to receive rtp/udp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to receive a udp stream encoded as h264. The exact command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -re -i "udp://239.192.1.2:1234" outfile.h264
```

The output I receive is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.2-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.2.1 (Debian 6.2.1-5) 20161124


configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libopencv --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-chromaprint --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument '9'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '99'.
Reading option '-re' ... matched as option 're' (read input at native frame rate) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'udp://@239.192.1.2:1234'.
Reading option 'outffff.h264' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument 9.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url udp://@239.192.1.2:1234.
Applying option re (read input at native frame rate) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: udp://@239.192.1.2:1234.
[udp @ 0x7f6638a36280] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x7f6638a36280] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f6638a56840] Statistics: 0 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

The problem with this is, obviously, that the ffmpeg process isn't detecting any incoming packets on that address which causes the process to hang.
I am, however, able to receive the stream using vlc, so I know that the packets are arriving. [Here is a link to a similar problem](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3313).

I thought, perhaps, it was a problem with reverse path filtering (as is mentioned in the link), but rp_filter is not set in /etc/sysctl.conf. I'm not quite sure what to do from here, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I removed the @, however this changes nothing.

The vlc command that works is:

```
vlc --miface eth1 rtp://@239.192.1.2:1234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using the localaddr parameter. I didn't realize that the host was sending on the eth1 interface and that I had to specify which interface to listen on. I'll leave the question in case anyone else has a similar problem.

The command that works: `ffmpeg -i udp://IP:PORT?localaddr=IP2 outfile.h264`

Comment: You should configure the multicast routes to avoid headaches.

Comment: This helped us with a strange bug that ocurred sometimes after updating Windows 10. The order of the NICs varied after the update and the ffprobe command we were issuing no longer worked. We were forced to rollback the update or reinstall the Operating System. Almost three years later and you really helped us!  Thanks  =)

Comment: This was reported as an issue 11 years back and closed 3 years ago, https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2415#no1.

Diff at http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blobdiff;f=libavformat/rtsp.c;h=4ecd70278073840c7ffd8efba44ad722036c138b;hp=e9fca034b42ec524afe469da80b349f58aaef695;hb=92c40ef882be115e72d2aa02f9032b7ce88f8537;hpb=2aceae1438ab4234161186712e9486e87be15be3.  So probably there should be some option to handle via command args, but I cannot find it

Comment: Thanks to this post, i recognized that for me it did not work when using "localhost" but it worked when using "127.0.0.1"